# How to storage data in Apex Controller for server side caching?

Tags: apex, soql, data-storage

Let's say I have the following method `getMyString()` in my Apex Controller.

I would like to refresh this SOQL query once in 30 minutes. Would it be possible to store the data in a 'local storage' type of way?

**Example Pseudo Solution**

```
if( LocalServerStorage.get( 'lastStoredDate' ) != new Date() )
{
    String myString = [ /* .. SOQL .. */ ];

    LocalServerStorage.store( 'myString', myString );
    LocalServerStorage.store( 'lastStoredDate', new Date() );
}
else
    String myString = LocalServerStorage.get( 'myString' );
```

**Sample SOQL code**

```
public static String getMyString()
{
    return [
        SELECT 
            MyString__c
        FROM 
            Strings__c
        WHERE
            Key = 'My String'
        WITH
            SECURITY_ENFORCED
        LIMIT 1
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you're looking for is probably the [The Org (platform) Cache](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_org_examples.htm) (as opposed to the Session Cache).

There's also a [relevant trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/platform_cache/platform_cache_use) to help get you started.

In a nutshell:

- You create a cache partition through the setup menu
- You call `.getPartition()` to retrieve it in code
- And you use that partition to `.put()` and `.get()` data